# Is it possible to Autowire a KSP generated class without writing any additional boilerplate?

Tags: spring, kotlin, dto

I have an interface for creating Dto/Domain mappers using Konvert, which uses KSP.

```kotlin
@Konverter
interface SimpleNoteMapper {
  fun toDto(note: SimpleNote): SimpleNoteDto
  fun toDomain(note: SimpleNoteDto): SimpleNote
}
```

The generated class is:

```kotlin
public object SimpleNoteMapperImpl : SimpleNoteMapper {
  @GeneratedKonverter(priority = 5_000)
  override fun toDto(note: SimpleNote): SimpleNoteDto = SimpleNoteDto(
    id = note.id,
    name = note.name
  )

  @GeneratedKonverter(priority = 5_000)
  override fun toDomain(note: SimpleNoteDto): SimpleNote = SimpleNote(
    id = note.id,
    name = note.name
  )
}
```

I want to inject the generated class using `@Autowired` into my `Controller`.

```kotlin
@RestController
class SimpleNotesController {
  @Autowired
  lateinit var simpleNoteMapper: SimpleNoteMapper
  [...]
}
```

But the error I get, is:

```
Field simpleNoteMapper in com.project.example.simplenotes.api.controller.SimpleNotesController required a bean of type 'com.project.example.simplenotes.api.mapper.SimpleNoteMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.project.example.simplenotes.api.mapper.SimpleNoteMapper' in your configuration.
```

I understand that I'd probably need to be able to add an annotation to that generated class, right? But that's not possible because it's generated. I can solve this by creating a Configuration for this mapper:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class MapperConfiguration {
  @Bean
  fun simpleNoteMapper(): SimpleNoteMapper {
    return SimpleNoteMapperImpl
  }
}
```

The application works, but I am unsure whether there isn't some way to remove this boilerplate, because I don't feel it's a good idea to create a configuration for each generated class. So I am looking for something that will simplify this to one annotation or to one class that would be able to cover all the Mappers. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it it seems there is some Spring behavior that automatically matches interfaces to implementations (e.g. `InterfaceA` matches to `InterfaceAImpl`), it doesn't work in this case, because Konvert is using `object` instead of `class` in the generated code (possibly).

Fortunately, Konvert has plugins, that solve this problem.

I had to add:

```kotlin
    implementation("io.mcarle:konvert-spring-annotations:2.4.0")
    ksp("io.mcarle:konvert-spring-injector:2.4.0")
```

to my `build.gradle.kts` file and then add the `@KComponent` annotation to the mapper interface:

```kotlin
@Konverter
@KComponent
interface SimpleNoteMapper {
  fun toDto(note: SimpleNote): SimpleNoteDto
  fun toDomain(note: SimpleNoteDto): SimpleNote
}
```

This generates a Spring-aware Mapper that can be injected without additional boilerplate.